# Can someone please explain how $60+\ln(64)-\ln(8)$ is equal to $60+\ln(8)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can someone please explain how $60+ \ln(64)- \ln(8)$ is equal to $60+\ln(8)$.
 I can't understand why this is true.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\ln (a) - \ln (b) = \ln(a/b) $, and it becomes clear.

Answer (score 3):

$ln(a)-ln(b)=ln(a/b)$ basic log property

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln64 = \ln8^2
\implies 60+\ln(64)−\ln(8) = 60+\ln8$$